# Jquery clickevent to check url

Tags: jquery

I am trying to implement a method that check if the link use click on is same on the current page nothing will happen. Otherwise go to the location of link user click on. I know that

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
```

to get the current link. but not sure how to get the links when user click on ...

Thank you very much ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using 1.7 and above this will update all links and future links on a page.

```
$("a").on("click", function(){
   var linkAddress = $(this).attr('href');
   if(linkAddress==pathname){
      return false;
   }
   return true;
});
```

Comment: That actually won't work. The href will be something like `http://site.com/foo` where the path name will only be `/foo/`

Comment: That is not true. `$(this).attr('href')` will return the `href` attribute. This is example would work but it depends how the links are created. It is also possible to use `js/jquery` and `regex` to check for `/foo/` and/or the `http://site.com`

Comment: Yeah, your function will return `href`... but `pathname` won't. Don't get me wrong, your code is correct (I have the same solution), I would just make a note of that difference.

Answer (score 1):

Bind the click event to all links. I'd use `location.href` to get the same page instead of `.pathname` too.

```
​$("a").click(function() {
    var pathname = window.location.href;
    console.log(pathname);
    if (this.href == pathname) {
        alert ("Same site. no go");
        return false;
    }
})​​
```

Comment: +1, I see what you mean. I think I read your comment incorrectly. I was just basing it off the OP and didn't go much beyond that. Nice work.

Answer (score 0):

u can strip anchor with this variable

```
var anchor = document.location.hash;
```

and check whats left behind. example

```
$(".button").click(function(){
   var anchor = document.location.hash;
   if ( anchor === '#myLink1' ) {//u can set ( if same page do nothing here)
     alert('ok');
   }else{ alert('not ok');}
});
```

html

```
<a class="button" href="#myLink1">1</a>
```